# How to set up selected value in Select field of ant design so that it remains compatible with validation rule in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, validation, antd

I am using Muse Antd Design Template with antd version `"antd": "^4.16.6"`.

I have an ant design form where I am populating data before submitting the form to edit an existing record.

`currencyConversionById` is the object/record I want to edit. Its structure is like this:-

```
currencyConversionById = {
    base_currency   : "USD",
    base_amount     : 1,
    to_currency     : "CAD",
    to_amount       : 2.45
}
```

`currencyList` is list of currencies like this:-

```
currencyList = [
    {
        currency        : "American Dollar",
        currency_code   : "USD"
    },
    {
        currency        : "Canadian Dollar",
        currency_code   : "CAD"
    }
]
```

The select field will have the currency list as its options and the option which matches with `currencyConversionById.to_currency`, will be displayed as selected.

This is the form:-

```
<Form {...layout} form={form} name={formTitle(window.location.pathname)} onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Form.Item name="base_currency" label="Base Currency" rules={CURRENCY_CODE_VALIDATION}>
    <Input value={baseCurrency} onChange={({ target: { value, } }) => setBaseCurrency(value)} readOnly={true}/>
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item name="base_amount" label="Base Amount">
    <Input value={baseCurrencyAmount} onChange={({ target: { value, } }) => setBaseCurrencyAmount(value)} readOnly={true}/>
    </Form.Item>
    {
    currencyListLoading
    ? <Loader message={"Loading Currency List"} description={"Listing all currency data"} type={"success"}/>
    : <Form.Item name="toCurrency" label="To Currency" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please, select a secondary currency' }]} initialvalue={toCurrency}>
        <Select placeholder="Select a option and change input text above" allowClear onChange={value => setToCurrency(value)} onLoad={value => setToCurrency(value)} value={toCurrency} defaultValue={toCurrency}>
            <Option key={0} value="0">None</Option>
            {currencyList && currencyList.length > 0 && currencyList.map((currency, indexCrn) => {
            return (
                <Option key={currency?.currency_code} value={currency?.currency_code}>{currency?.currency_code}</Option>
                )
            })}
        </Select>
        </Form.Item>
    }
    <Form.Item name="to_amount" label="To Amount" rules={AMOUNT_VALIDATION}>
    <Input value={toCurrencyAmount} onChange={value => setToCurrencyAmount(value)} onLoadedData={value => setToCurrencyAmount(value)}/>
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">{formCardTitle(window.location.pathname)}</Button> &nbsp;
    <Button htmlType="button" onClick={onReset}>
        Reset
    </Button>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

While populating the data in the form, I did this:-

```
  useEffect(() => {
  if (currencyConversionById !== null)
  {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      base_currency : currencyConversionById?.base_currency,
      base_amount   : currencyConversionById?.base_amount,
      to_currency   : currencyConversionById?.to_currency.toString(),
      to_amount     : currencyConversionById?.to_amount.toString()
    });
    setToCurrency(currencyConversionById?.to_currency);
  }  
}, [currencyConversionById])
```

Using `form.setFieldsValue` I could set the values for all the text inputs, but for Select option, I had to do this:-

```
const [toCurrency, setToCurrency]  = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    if (currencyConversionById !== null)
    {
        ------------------------
        ------------------------
        setToCurrency(currencyConversionById?.to_currency);
    }  
}, [currencyConversionById])
```

Using `setToCurrency()`, I set up `toCurrency` value as `"CAD"`, and then in the form, passed it was `initialValue` and `defaultValue` like this:-

```
<Form.Item name="toCurrency" label="To Currency" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please, select a secondary currency' }]} initialvalue={toCurrency}>
<Select placeholder="Select a option and change input text above" allowClear onChange={value => setToCurrency(value)} onLoad={value => setToCurrency(value)} value={toCurrency} defaultValue={toCurrency}>
    <Option key={0} value="0">None</Option>
    {currencyList && currencyList.length > 0 && currencyList.map((currency, indexCrn) => {
    return (
        <Option key={currency?.currency_code} value={currency?.currency_code}>{currency?.currency_code}</Option>
        )
    })}
</Select>
</Form.Item>
```

By doing this, "CAD" is displayed as selected option. However, when I am trying to submit the function, the validation rule for to_currency is triggered.

[image]

Why is it happening like this? Since an option is already shown as selected, the required validation should not be fired. But don't know why this validation is keep on getting triggered.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initialValues` form property to set initial values

> Components inside Form.Item with name property will turn into
> controlled mode, which makes defaultValue not work anymore. Please try
> initialValues of Form to set default value.